# module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v2.keras.layers' has no attribute 'CuDNNLSTM'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

When I write `tf.keras.layers.LSTM`, I get the warning

`Note that this layer is not optimized for performance. Please use tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM for better performance on GPU.`

But when I change the layer to `tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM`, I get the error

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v2.keras.layers' has no attribute 'CuDNNLSTM'`

Tensorflow version is 2.0.0-alpha0, Keras version is 2.2.4-tf.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: There is no `CuDNNLSTM` layer in `tf 2.0` yet. See the available layers here https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers

Comment: Use `tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM()`, not `tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, in TensorFlow 2.0 we should just use:

```py
tf.keras.layers.LSTM
```

which, despite the warning, **will** use the GPU.

The warning message incorrectly existed in the `2.0.0-alpha0` version but has since been removed in `2.0.0-beta1`

If for some reason you specifically need the original implementation of `tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` then you can use `tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` but this would be an edge case.