# Tensorflow 2.0 save trained model for serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Please help me. I am using Tensorflow 2.0 GPU.
I train the model and save in .h5 format

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.CuDNNLSTM(self._window_size, return_sequences=True),
                               input_shape=(self._window_size, x_train.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=self._dropout, seed=self._seed))
model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.CuDNNLSTM((self._window_size * 2), return_sequences=True)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=self._dropout, seed=self._seed))
model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.CuDNNLSTM(self._window_size, return_sequences=False)))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=1))
model.add(layers.Activation('linear'))
model.summary()

model.compile(
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer='adam'
)
# обучаем модель
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=self._epochs,
    batch_size=self._batch_size,
    shuffle=False,
    validation_split=0.1
)

model.save('rts.h5')
```

Then I load this model and use it for forecasting and everything works.

```
model = keras.models.load_model('rts.h5')
y_hat = model.predict(x_test)
```

But the question arose of using a trained model in Tensorflow Serving. And the model in .h5 format is not accepted.
I run:

```
sudo docker run --gpus 1 -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/home/alex/PycharmProjects/TensorflowServingTestData/RtsModel,target=/models/rts_model -e MODEL_NAME=rts_model -t tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu
```

But the question arose of using a trained model in Tensorflow Serving. And the model in .h5 format is not accepted.
I run:
And I get the error:

```
tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:267] No versions of servable rts_model found under base path /models/rts_model
```

I try to save the trained model as described here, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#using_savedmodel_with_estimators:
[image]

And I get the error:

```
ValueError: Layer has 2 states but was passed 0 initial states.
```

I tried to save the model as follows, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model:
[image]

And have the same error:

```
ValueError: Layer has 2 states but was passed 0 initial states.
```

The only thing that works to save the model in the format for Tensorflow Serving is:

```
keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, 'saved_model/1/')
```

Saved model work in Serving. But I get a warning that this method is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

```
Instructions for updating:
Please use `model.save(..., save_format="tf")` or `tf.keras.models.save_model(..., save_format="tf")`.
```

And it closed me.
When I try to use these methods, it gives an error.
When I use what works, writes that it is deprecated.

Please, help.
How to save a trained model in Tensorflow 2.0. so that it can be used for Tensorflow Serving.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to fix this too!

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761337/module-tensorflow-python-keras-api-v2-keras-layers-has-no-attribute-cudnnlst) the normal LSTM (i.e. `tf.keras.layers.LSTM`) will use GPU, and should be used in general over the cuDNNLSTM class unless you specifically need the original implementation (not sure why you would).

According to [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) the normal LSTM will use cuDNN implementation if some requirements are met (see below).

When using this LSTM layer, I could successfully save to the tf output type, just using `model.save_model('output_path', save_format='tf')`

Requirements for LSTM using cuDNN are as follows (note that all the requirements are met with the defaults):

> If a GPU is available and all the arguments to the layer meet the requirement of the CuDNN kernel (see below for details), the layer will use a fast cuDNN implementation.
>
> The requirements to use the cuDNN implementation are:
>
> 1. `activation == tanh`
> 2. `recurrent_activation == sigmoid`
> 3. `recurrent_dropout == 0`
> 4. unroll is False
> 5. use_bias is True
>    Inputs are not masked or strictly right padded.